# Clear auto number field on a Form using clear button

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm new to MS ACCESS, I would like to know if there is a way to clear an auto number field using a clear button. I've tried to follow some videos on you particularly [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ri2Y9-16AEo&t=195s) but it seems to be not the proper way on how to deal or create an auto number field.

This is the image is the sample of the form which I'm experimenting with this particular subject.
[image]

And this image is the error code which I'm getting right after I clicked the clear button.
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Below is the code I use for this experiment[image].

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to clear autonumber field, it handled automatically. So, remove EnployeeID field from INSERT statement and delete rows with `Me.txtEmployeeID` from clear procedure

Comment: And you should set the values to ___Null___, not an empty string("").

Comment: I reviewed my post and I noticed that I mistakenly made a double entry in the clear statements for the "txtEmployeeID", but I re-write them and follow your instructions but I'm still getting an error.

Comment: Please make sure that info.EmployeeID field has Autonumber data type and you don't assign any values to txtEmployeeID anywhere in the code: You should see ID number on the form when you clearing it.

Comment: BTW, Are you sure that your text boxes on main form are bounded to the table?

Comment: If you mean that if the whole form including its own elements such as text box and subform are connected to the table then yes they are, in fact if I can save the entry into the table after I hit the Add button.

Comment: Video you referred to is about editing data in table using UNBOUND controls and ID field there was NOT autonumber. For bound controls (with column name in Control Source property) and autonumber field should be used another technology. In this case you don't have to handle ID field (display only) and don't need to use SQL for inserting, just move current record to new record and enter the data. So, please determine which technology you want to use and use it in proper way.

Answer (score 0):

- The **AutoNumber** Data Type is assigned automatically and can't be
  changed. Also once you enter data into some other field like Employee
  Name(New Record event initiated), access will assign a value to the
  **AutoNumber** let's say 1. If you press Esc, access will cancel the edit. Next time you create a new record access will assign the value 2 and so forth. Unless you repair the database then access will reset the **AutoNumber** counter.
- If you want a data type that you change its value, you need to change the Data Type to **Number**. In this case you need to assign each value by code or by the user input.